# During Synchronization... Failed To Excute the command 'SelectRowCommand' For table 'abc' the translation was rolled backed

Tags: sql-server, synchronization

Hi During Synchronizing My Database I got These Expectations ....

> Failed To Excute the command 'SelectRowCommand' For table 'abc' the
>   transation was rolled backed .Ensure the Command Syntax is Correct...
>
> A network -related or instance specific error occurred while
>   establishing  a connection to SQL Server . Server was not found or was
>   not accessible .Verfiy .....

Comment: i think server is disconnected

Comment: The Table which i am Synchronizing had Too Many Rows...